# The import org.apache.cxf cannot be resolvedJava

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm new to Java / SpringBoot.

I just created a SpringBoot project with Gradle, and I can't use :

```
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
```

I tried to import apache cxf with gradle with:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf', version: '3.3.3', ext: 'pom'
```

in the build.gradle, and then:

1. Automatic build with VSCode
2. Manual build with `gradlew build`

And after that, I still can't use `org.apache.cxf`

What am I missing ?

Comment: `ext: pom` is including the maven pom no dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I have seen, the dependencies should be:

```
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>  
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>  
        <version>x.x.x</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>  
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>  
        <version>x.x.x</version>
    </dependency>
```

or in Gradle syntax:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:x.x.x'
    compile 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:x.x.x'
```

Comment: It worked. Sorry, last time I worked with Java was with Java 1.4 so I'm total newbie !